# Trouble understanding the use of dot product in this example?

Tags: vector, glsl

Usually, I use the dot product of 2 vectors either to find out how perpendicular they are or the cosine of the angle between them. In this shader, a toon shader, the dot product is used on 2 colors and I cannot wrap my head around what exactly this is doing.

```
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D backBuffer;

void main(void)
{

  vec4 to_gray = vec4(0.3,0.59,0.11,0);
  float x1 = dot(to_gray,  texture2D(backBuffer,vec2((gl_FragCoord.xy
      + vec2(1.0,1.0)) /resolution.xy)).rgba);
  float x0 = dot(to_gray,  texture2D(backBuffer,vec2((gl_FragCoord.xy
      + vec2(-1.0,-1.0)) /resolution.xy)).rgba);
  float x3 = dot(to_gray,  texture2D(backBuffer,vec2((gl_FragCoord.xy
      + vec2(1.0,-1.0)) /resolution.xy)).rgba);
  float x2 = dot(to_gray,  texture2D(backBuffer,vec2((gl_FragCoord.xy
      + vec2(-1.0,1.0)) /resolution.xy)).rgba);
  float edge = (x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0);
  float edge2 = (x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2);
  edge += edge2;
  vec4 color =  texture2D(backBuffer,vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy  / resolution.xy));

    gl_FragColor = max(color - vec4(edge, edge, edge, edge) * 12.0,
        vec4(0,0,0,color.a));
}
```

Comment: I do not know what this code is doing, exactly, but dot product is also how you project one vector onto another.  That is, if `A` is a vector and `e` is a unit vector, `A . e` is the projection of A along `e`.  You can use this to convert a vector into its components in any orthonormal basis.

Comment: For those interested, the values for to_gray come from the CIE human vision sensitivity curve, which has its maximum on green and a strong decay at red and blue wavelengths (R 30%, G 59%, B 11%).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "geometric" scalar (dot) product properties don't really matter in this case. What you have here is an ordinary conversion of some `(R, G, B)` color to the corresponding grayscale intensity `I` in accordance with the formula

```
I = R * 0.30 + G * 0.59 + B * 0.11
```

(You can learn more about these coefficients here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems).

As you can immediately see this formula looks like a scalar product of two vectors: one is our color `(R, G, B)` and the other is `(0.30, 0.59, 0.11)`. So, the author of the code just used the "dot product" function to evaluate this formula for four different color values obtained at four different points: point `gl_FragCoord.xy` shifted in four different directions (like an `x` pattern).

In other words, the dot product in this case is not used on "two colors", as you seemed to assume initially. It is used on a color (pixel taken from `backBuffer` at some coordinates) and a conversion coefficient vector `(0.30, 0.59, 0.11)` (aptly named `to_gray`). The latter is not really a color. It just a vector of conversion coefficients. You can think of it as a "color" if you want, but there's not much sense in it.

That's it for the dot product.

Then they do some extra computations to combine the four grayscale values into a single grayscale value. Then they use that grayscale value to modify the original color at point `gl_FragCoord.xy` (gray values are subtracted from RGB values at `gl_FragCoord.xy`). The purpose of all this is not fully clear without context.

Comment: "(I hope I don't have to explain where these coefficients come from)."  I know very little about graphics things, but this seems to be an interesting piece of knowledge.  Can we get a hint?

Comment: @colechristensen: The coefficients are taken from NTSC TV standard and are supposed to represent relative sensitivity of human eye to each of the three basic colors. These coefficients are supposed to be used with NTSC RGB values only, but in practice they are often used to convert sRBG color values to a single luminosity value as well. (Although for sRGB color space the proper set of coefficients is actually 0.21, 0.72, 0.07)

Comment: Basically, the strongest impact on the overall luminosity (by far) is made by the green channel (60-70%). It is followed by red channel (around 20%-30%). And the blue channel makes the smallest impact on the perceived luminosity (only 10%).

Comment: good answer but I have to state that this is a terrible abuse of the dot product. Just because by chance the grey scale can be done with dot does not make it a good choice. Don't try this at home people!

Comment: And on a added note, I finally understand dot products!

Comment: It's worth noting that this conversion can actually be thought of in a conventional dot product sense as a projection to the luminosity vector. It's not simply a clever abuse of the maths lining up.